# How to write shorter day names on calendar when app is deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, calendar

I'm using `asp calendar` in my app. Everything is fine when I run it locally. But when I deploy the app, the days are getting longer and it floats. I have already set `dayNameFormat` to `short`.

```
local(Mon), deploy(monday)
```

I didn't understand why that happens. Can you help about this ?

Comment: Can you post the code showing the problem?

Comment: I have added the codes

Answer (score 0):

The day names are based on the server's local settings. See Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.daynameformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: No, I use multiple languages. No problem in English, turkish, Arabian but if georgian is chosen, this problem occurs

Comment: Where do you change the language - on the server regional settings or the application itself? So if you have English you get Mon (dev) and Mon (prod), but if you set Georgian you get xyz (dev) and xyzabc (prod)?

Comment: I change it in application itself . Yes like u said, interesting problem.